# Golang - Convert hijri to gregorian date to get holidays (via an API or not)

Tags: go, gregorian-calendar, hijri

So I want to get [Eid Al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr) (first three days of the month of the tenth month) and [Eid Al-Adha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha)(10-to-13th days of final month) in order to calculate the working days in countries e.g Turkey etc.
And as Islamic calendar is a lunar one, it varies in every single Gregorian year. I'd prefer finding them with a piece of Go code rather than persisting their Gregorian equivalents for each year into a database.

How to do that with Go? It is also ok fetching them through a *free* api too.[HolidayAPI](https://holidayapi.com/) seems to find it but only works for past years' data in free edition.

Comment: Go wrapper for holiday API
https://github.com/joshtronic/go-holidayapi
Article about holiday API https://joshtronic.com/2013/12/02/holiday-api-free-ready-fork/

I suggest you pay for the service if you don't want to build it yourself.